# Aligning a TeX Code appropriately in LyX

Tags: lyx, r

I'm a bit new to using LyX to typeset my R code (using the `Rnw(knitr)` module) into a pdf. While working on it, I came across a problem. Say, for example, I have a dataset in the form of a table like this:

| Injury | Seatbelt_Yes | Seatbelt_No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| none | 12813 | 65963 |
| minimal | 647 | 4000 |
| minor | 359 | 2642 |
| major | 42 | 303 |

I wrote a code in `R` to create a dataframe like this, as follows:

```
CarInjury<-data.frame(injury=factor(c("none","minimal","minor","major")),seatbelt_yes=c(12813,647,359,42),seatbelt_no=c(65963,4000,2642,303))
```

This does the job of creating a table just fine, even returns the output correctly when I run the file, but, the code just ignores and runs off outside the page, partly at the right-hand side of the pdf. Like this:
[image: Screenshot-1]

In the above image, it can be clearly seen that the part from `seatbelt_no=c(65963,4000,2642,303))` till the end has been '*cut*' out of the page.

A similar example: I used the dataset **airquality** to plot some graphs. Here was what I did:

```
naairquality<-na.omit(airquality)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==5,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==5,]$Solar.R,pch=16,col="Blue",xlim=c(1,31),ylim=c(0,400),xlab="Day",ylab=NA,main="Solar Radiation and Temperature vs. Days for May-Sep,1973")
par(new=T)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==5,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==5,]$Temp,pch=18,col="Yellow",ylim=c(0,400),xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab=NA,ylab=NA,type='l',lwd=1.5)
par(new=T)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==6,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==6,]$Solar.R,pch=16,col="dodgerBlue",xlim=c(1,31),ylim=c(0,400),xlab=NA,ylab=NA,xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
par(new=T)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==6,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==6,]$Temp,pch=18,col="Orange",ylim=c(0,400),xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab=NA,ylab=NA,type='l',lwd=1.5)
par(new=T)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==7,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==7,]$Solar.R,pch=16,col="deepskyBlue",xlim=c(1,31),ylim=c(0,400),xlab=NA,ylab=NA,xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
par(new=T)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==7,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==7,]$Temp,pch=18,col="Gold",ylim=c(0,400),xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab=NA,ylab=NA,type='l',lwd=1.5)
par(new=T)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==8,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==8,]$Solar.R,pch=16,col="Blue4",xlim=c(1,31),ylim=c(0,400),xlab=NA,ylab=NA,xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
par(new=T)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==8,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==8,]$Temp,pch=18,col="Red",ylim=c(0,400),xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab=NA,ylab=NA,type='l',lwd=1.5)
par(new=T)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==9,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==9,]$Solar.R,pch=16,col="seagreen",xlim=c(1,31),ylim=c(0,400),xlab=NA,ylab=NA,xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
par(new=T)
plot(naairquality[naairquality$Month==9,]$Day,naairquality[naairquality$Month==9,]$Temp,pch=18,col="Brown",ylim=c(0,400),xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab=NA,ylab=NA,type='l',lwd=1.5)
par(xpd=T)
legend("topright",c("May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep"),col=c("blue","dodgerblue","deepskyblue","blue4","seagreen"),pch=16,title="Solar Radiation",horiz=T,cex=0.65)
legend("topleft",c("May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep"),col=c("yellow","orange","gold","red","brown"),lty=1,title="Temperature",horiz=T,lwd=1.5,cex=0.65)
```

The graph did come out fine(as I expected):
[image: Screenshot-2]

But the code didn't quite '*fit*' in the page (again '*cut*' out at the right side):
[image: Screenshot-3]

[image: Screenshot-4]

I want to know if there are some tweaks/methods in LyX that would automatically break the line, in a code, if some part of the code doesn't fit within the width of the page. Something like this (the CarInjury example):

```
CarInjury<-data.frame(injury=factor(c("none","minimal","minor","major")),seatbelt_yes=c(12813,647,359,42),
seatbelt_no=c(65963,4000,2642,303))
```

---

**Note:** I thought of changing the inside and outside borders of the document, but that's not feasible for a long line of code (as in the `airquality` plot code). I even set the size of the font inside the TeX code insertion box to `small`, but that too didn't help much.

**Note:** The codes were a part of an assignment that has long been submitted (later part of April this year). That should explain the serial number of the questions in the screenshots. I hope to learn any new tweaks in LyX(if any) that can solve this problem of mine so that I can typeset my future documents in a better way.

**Note:** I apologize if the title of this post is a bit vague according to the content. But I couldn't really think of any other appropriate title for this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** Format the code manually. Probably the best option for readability:

```
CarInjury <- data.frame(
  injury=factor(c("none","minimal","minor","major")),
  seatbelt_yes=c(12813,647,359,42),
  seatbelt_no=c(65963,4000,2642,303))
```

The output will be the same.

**Option 2:** Add the options `tidy=TRUE,tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60)` to the R chunk ("Options" box). Note that this options will disregard your manual format, if any.

[image: mwe]

[image: mwe2]

Comment: The second option didn't work here, but the first one just ran fine.

Comment: Maybe  you will need  install /update formatR for the second option.